# Why am I getting this "missing index for constraint..." error on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm at a loss here, the ordering of tables and foreign keys all seem fine to me.

**Here is the error message in it's entirety:**

```
ALTER TABLE user_reviews ADD FOREIGN KEY (`media_year`) REFERENCES titles(`year`).
```

> Error Code: 1822.
> Failed to add the foreign key constraint.
> Missing
> index for constraint 'user_reviews_ibfk_3' in the referenced table
> 'titles'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wants you to add an index on the field `year` in table `titles`.
Seems to be, creating a FK does not create an index behind the scenes on the referenced field.
It is required by the mysql version/config you use.

Comment: Thanks, I've used MySQL a bit and never ran into this requirement before. For anyone wondering I am using the latest version (8.0.26).